# Switch Design for door control

Tags: led, mosfet-driver

I am designing a switch for vehicle door control. The details are as follows:

1. Switch is non latching and it communicates with vehicle ECU on hardwire.
2. When the switch is not pressed it should send 12V to ECU on a hardwire and ECU will send signal to turn on a white LED inside switch.
3. When the switch is pressed it should send 12V on another hardwire to ECU and ECU will send another signal to turn on a amber LED inside switch.
4. The circuit will have surge protection.

We cannot use microcontroller for this, we have to design the circuit with minimum number of components.

Can somebody help me designing this circuit ?

Comment: you forgot to ask a question ... please add a clear, answerable question to your post

Comment: the question has to be about the circuit  ... what use is a `yes` answer to `can somebody help me?` anyway?

Comment: Are you actually designing the "switch" or the "ECU" system or both? You can buy switches (or push buttons) with one or more LEDs already built in.  Can you show what you've designed so far?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's homework with no attempt at a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's is an example using this [SPDT PB switch](https://sten-eswitch-13110800-production.s3.amazonaws.com/system/asset/product_line/data_sheet/233/PVA3.pdf) with RGB LEDs built in.
(One potential source is [Digikey](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/e-switch/PVA3F2B0SS3R1/8539887?utm_adgroup=&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=PMax%20Shopping_Product_Low%20ROAS%20Categories&utm_term=&utm_content=&utm_id=go_cmp-20243063506_adg-_ad-__dev-c_ext-_prd-8539887_sig-EAIaIQobChMI8sGQ3b-2gwMVpkxHAR3yEwmMEAQYASABEgKSuvD_BwE&gad_source=1&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI8sGQ3b-2gwMVpkxHAR3yEwmMEAQYASABEgKSuvD_BwE)).

You would wire up the LEDs as needed to create the color you want at each switch position.

As shown when the switch is unactivated the color output would be White since all three LEDs would be enabled. When the switch is pressed the NC pin opens and the Blue LED is disabled, the combined color then changes to Amber, since only the Red and Green LEDs would remain enabled.

Since I wouldn't want to take all the fun out of designing this I didn't calculate all of the component values.

To select the appropriate current limiting resistor for each LED use:
R = (V\${_i}{_n}\$ - V\${_f}{_L}{_E}{_D}\$) / I\${_L}{_E}{_D}\$

To create a simple surge protection for the circuit you can use a Zener diode shunt and a low current series fuse. You did not list what the potential surge voltage might be so the Zener voltage, power rating, and the fuse amperage need to be selected with that in mind.
.

[image]
.

In case you are persistent in using a feed back system from the ECU (with added wiring) to control the LED colors you could use simple diodes to direct the signals to the correct LED group. See the modified circuit below. Here the YELLOW signal line enables only the Red and Green LEDs, while the WHITE signal line enables the Red, Green, and Blue LEDs.

This alternate arrangement would also give you the option to dim the LEDs if that feature were desired. You would use a PWM signal on the YELLOW and WHITE signal lines.
.

[image]

.